# Short story about a robot being tested for sentience that saves its interrogator from a bomb placed by a terrorist

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots, anthology-book

The story starts with an interrogation room where a robot is being tested for sentience. A terrorist places a bomb, and the robot the realizes the ship is going to explode, so it saves the interrogator and itself by making use of an escape pod. They escape the explosion, but the human is damaged. The robot realizes he won't survive and there was no mind back-up to restore him to a new body, as was their way. The robot has a moral issue. If you know it, I won't spoil it for everyone else.

Comment: Put the spoilers behind this: >! It will hide it from people who don’t click on, so that people not looking for spoilers won’t see them

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: logicDictates, it has the feel of late 70's to mid 80's. i've had it for sometime, but cant seem to find it. honestly though it could be older or newer.. i have a number of old anthology's and collected shorts from the 50's to the late 80's. this was various authors, but that story had a familiar feel to the writing, PK Dick, J Parnell.. i told someone about it, they wanted to read it.. cant even id the story, b44n going through my collecteds and have not found it.